# Create 'bottom tab' in div with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, border, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a series of Bootstrap coloumns to mimic a website design I've been given.

[image]

These columns have a blue border with the bottom of the div with a much thicker border. 
A border is of little use as it alters the dimensions and available space so I tried to simply create a div within it to use `background-color` with `width:100%` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Can anyone show me the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

```css
.featuredCatalog {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 5px solid #00AEF0;
}
.shopTab {
  background-color: #00AEF0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
    <div class="shopTab">
      <h4>Shop Now</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
    <h4>Shop Now</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
    <h4>Shop Now</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
    <h4>Shop Now</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
    <h4>Shop Now</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing is that the 'Shop Now' h4 tag has a top and bottom margin which is creating the white gap below. If this is taken off the 'Shop Now' blue bar is positioned at the bottom of the container and it looks like how I think you need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is code snippet solves your issue and create product display like the image.

```css
.shopTab {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: #00AEF0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26%;
}

.product-display {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #00AEF0;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 160px;
    max-width: 160px;
}

.product-display img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 74%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <div class="product-display">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
      <div class="shopTab">
        <h4>Shop Now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <div class="product-display">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
      <div class="shopTab">
        <h4>Shop Now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <div class="product-display">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
      <div class="shopTab">
        <h4>Shop Now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <div class="product-display">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
      <div class="shopTab">
        <h4>Shop Now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 featuredCatalog">
    <div class="product-display">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/191x131">
      <div class="shopTab">
        <h4>Shop Now</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked almost great, however, the only issues are that on desktop, the tab overlaps the image. Is it possible to have it below the image or just smaller? And also, the above code seems to make each product box stretch to 2-3x usual height when viewing on my iPhone.

Comment: Are you going to use Fixed width to the main container "product-display"? If yes, give it here. I'll fix the issues

Comment: That's right, yeah. The whole page is wrapped in `<div class="container">`. You can see the page in action [here](https://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com). Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer. A few CSS changes applied

Comment: That seems to have done the trick quite nicely! Thanks very much.

Comment: May be you should accept the answer so when someone face problem like you were facing, they get solution.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'd left the office. Marked now. Thanks for the help.